# saved model.h5 convert to tensorflow file format

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model, tensorflow-lite

after some searching and asked a question here i found a way to save the entire model of keras inside one file which is **example.h5** for later use i found an answer here

https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/

my previous question is

[keras save the model weights to one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60297837/keras-save-the-model-weights-to-one-file)

and now i have to change to the mode.h5 convert it to tflite for tensorflow lite then i can used inside the mobile app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [keras save the model weights to one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60297837/keras-save-the-model-weights-to-one-file)

Comment: did you read my question ?? yes from previous question i save the entire mode in one file which is example.h5 and now i have to convert it to example.tflite  is that clear?

Comment: I answered that in the first part of the answer already I think

Comment: What is your exact question? I answered how to save a model to file and then how to load it and convert it to TFLite, Should I post an answer here as well and focus on the converter?

Comment: import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

model1 = load_model("model.h5")

# Convert the model.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model1)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'convert'

Comment: your answer gives me this error now what ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208123/discussion-between-igna-and-black-snow).